# Insert .php file in another .php file and only execute a function()

Tags: php, include

I know the title is messed up, but basically I have: news.php which is kind of a dashboard where I get all news from DB and I can perform actions on them (update, delete, insert new) and also I display them in a traditional way (tables). The problem is I want the title of the first news to be displayed on my homepage(footer), but when I include the news.php file with`include()`, the hole code it's included and on the home page I get all the things I have in news.php, all the news, the buttons (edit, add, delete) and everything else. Is there any way of including one .php file but not displaying it ? I want to create a function that only displays the title of the first news but I can't because the hole code is imported and displayed.

Thank you for your quick answers. Having only this small problem, I'll just create another file where I get the latest news without using frameworks

Comment: Refactor so that function you want is in a library file, then include it in `news.php` and everywhere else you want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function library so that you can call specific segments if you want.

But here's a quick shortcut. copy news.php into news2.php. go into news2.php delete all the parts you don't want; include news2.php instead

Comment: I followed your suggestion because it's the simplest in my case, thank you

Comment: PHP coders of the world, keep producing sloppy code! good job! -.-

Answer (score 0):

You could try making another single file called firstnews.php which would only retrieve that particular first news item and include that.

You should maybe read up on MVC frameworks, its a good way to seperate data retrieval, manipulation, and then actually showing the data. For example one php file would hold a function that retrieves all news item, and another function that only gets the latest news article. Then the actual file which shows the user data would simply choose which function it wants to use.

Its a lot to get into, but the codeigniter framework is a great way to get familiar with MVC frameworks and it will open a lot of doors for you.

[CodeIgniter Homepage](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)

[Manual on how to setup and use CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)

For now though try just making a seperate php file that only retrieves the latest news item instead of all of them and include that.

Hope this helps!

-Gui